# How long are solar years on other planets?

Tags: axial-tilt

Solar years for other planets are hard to find anywhere.  Besides almost tiltless Mercury, how long does it take fora tropical year to pass on each planet? That is, how long does it take for those planets to pass through the seasons, slight or not.

Comment: Stable tropical years require stable axial precession, which Earth has, due to our Moon. OTOH, the tilt of Mars is much more variable. https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/images/pia15095-changes-in-tilt-of-mars-axis But I guess that's not an issue if you're just interested in relatively short time spans.

Answer (score 3):

You look for the [sidereal period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_period) or orbital period which describes how long it takes the planet to once fully move along its orbit around the Sun, independent of where Earth is.

This number is given for basically every astronomical body in its descriptions and in the typical lists (including on the page linked above). These are the ones of the 8 planets in our system and one of the most distant known dwarf planets, Sedna:

- Mercury: 88 days
- Venus 225 days
- Earth 365.25636 (solar) days
- Mars 687 days (1.8 years)
- Jupiter 11.86 years
- Saturn 30 years
- Uranus 84 years
- Neptune 165 years
- Sedna 12000 years